# How to create sub-menu when click menu in magister bootstrap theme?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have just used bootstrap theme magister.
Now I want add sub-menu in menu dropdown when click menu, but I'm wrong something. You can see it and give advise for me.

```css
.mainmenu .dropdown-menu {
 top: -14em;
 left: 0px;
 font-size: 13px;
 padding:0;
 background:none;
 border:0 none;
 border-radius: 2px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 display:block;
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: all .45s;
    -moz-transition: all .45s;
         transition: all .45s;
}
.mainmenu .dropdown-menu .active { 
 font-weight:bold;
}
.mainmenu .open .dropdown-menu { 
 top:2px;
 opacity:1;
}
.mainmenu .dropdown-menu a { 
 padding:10px 10px;
 margin:0;
 color:white;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
         border-radius: 2px;
}
.mainmenu .dropdown-menu a:hover { 
 background:rgba(255,255,255,.1);
 color:white;
 padding:10px 8px 10px 12px;
}
.mainmenu .dropdown-menu ul li ul a{
 list-style:none;
 background:red;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
.mainmenu .dropdown-menu ul li ul a:hover{
 color:blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu" >
  <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">submenu</a></li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">submenu 1 link</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">submenu 2 link</a></li>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#">submenu 2-1 link</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">submenu 2-2 link</a></li>
 </ul>
 <li><a href="#">submenu 3 link</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way you can create dropdown, but theme of which you provide link, having navigation which is collapsable.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<h2>Dropdowns</h2>
<p>The .dropdown class is used to indicate a dropdown menu.</p>
<p>Use the .dropdown-menu class to actually build the dropdown menu.</p>                                          
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
<span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
<li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```